# Bind Aggregation Relative to Parent Selection

Tags: sapui5

I have an XML view and a controller.

My model data is bound to the `sap.m.Table`. The problem is that I have to bind the `"items"` relative to a certain array element of my model.

These are my model data:

```json
[{
  "type": "01",
  "items": [{
    "date": "20150720",
    "amount": 53.20,
    "paytype": "Cash"
  }, {
    "date": "20150720",
    "amount": 23.20,
    "paytype": "Cash"
  }]
}, {
  "type": "02",
  "items": [{
    "date": "20150720",
    "amount": 515.6,
    "paytype": "Credit Card"
  }, {
    "date": "20150720",
    "amount": 3,
    "paytype": "Something else"
  }]
}]
```

I want to bind my table to the `"items"` property according to a selection change of my `Select` control which has fields like "type" property bound.

How can I write the path of the items property of my table? `"data>/items/"` didn't work.

I thought about solution to bind the path value to an external model
`pathModel` and to update its property according to a selection change of the select object like that:

My view:

```xml
<Table
  id="dataTable"
  items="{path>pathUrl}"
>
```

My controller:

```js
newPath = "data>/"+ countPath +"/items/";
currentView.getModel("path").setProperty("/pathUrl", newPath);
```

But it's not working either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My solution, and i think that it's the best one: To create a independant model for the table and to fill it with the items of my first model when i change the select control.

This is my code:

```
            var itemsTable  = currentView.getModel( "AdjustData" ); // this is my new mode bound to the table
            var data        = currentView.getModel( "data" ).getData();

            //  Set Type payment items
            jQuery.each( data , function( index , item ) {
                if ( item.type == mode ) {
                    itemsTable.setData( item.items );
                }
            });
```

Comment: Could you add to this how to assign the itemsTable model to the table please?

Comment: @VanquishedWombat If you're wondering how to bind aggregation relatively, take a look at this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/51192293/5846045

Answer (score 2):

The question describes a typical use case for the concept [Element Binding](https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/#/topic/91f05e8b6f4d1014b6dd926db0e91070).

### View

```xml
<Select
  forceSelection="false"
  change=".onSelectionChange"
  items="{myModel>/}"
>
  <core:Item
    key="{myModel>typeKey}"
    text="Type {myModel>type}"
  />
</Select>
```

```xml
<Table id="myTable" items="{myModel>items}">
  <items>
    <ColumnListItem>
      <Text text="{myModel>paytype}"/>
      <Text text="{myModel>amount}"/>
    </ColumnListItem>
  </items>
  <!-- ... -->
</Table>
```

### Controller

```js
onSelectionChange: function(event) {
  const selectedItem = event.getParameter("selectedItem");
  this.byId("myTable").bindElement({
    path: selectedItem.getBindingContext("myModel").getPath(), // e.g. "/1"
    model: "myModel",
  });
},
```

Once an item is selected from the `Select` control, the `onSelectionChange` is invoked with the selected item as a parameter. That item contains a **binding context** <sup>[API](https://ui5.sap.com/#/api/sap.ui.model.Context)</sup> which can be retrieved via `.getBindingContext(/*modelName*/)`. Calling `getPath()` from it will return the absolute path of the bound data. In case of a JSONModel, the path will be index-like such as `"/0"`, `"/1"`, etc. In case of ODataModel; `"/ProductSet('123')"` for example.

The absolute binding path should be then assigned to the API `bindElement`.<sup>[API](https://ui5.sap.com/#/api/sap.ui.core.Element/methods/bindElement)</sup> All the *relative* binding paths within the element target, e.g. `"{myModel>items}"`, can be then finally resolved showing the data to the UI.

---

Here is a working example using your data: [**https://embed.plnkr.co/FOEY1JZIKFAJTApe/**](https://embed.plnkr.co/FOEY1JZIKFAJTApe?show=controller/Home.controller.js,preview).

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I have created a simple Plunker example that shows a simple way to achieve what you are looking for. [Check it out here.](http://plnkr.co/edit/LTKYo1D30ewfqvSN06U1)

```
onSelectChange: function (ev) {
          var list = this.getView().byId("myList");
          var index = ev.getParameter("selectedItem").getKey();
          list.bindItems("/" + index + "/items",
            new sap.m.StandardListItem({
              title: "{amount}",
            description: "{paytype}"
            })
        );
        }
```

There is a sap.m.Select control with a change handler in which we bind the table to the proper items array.

Comment: it's ok, but i have the template of my columns and cells int my xml file

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this:

```
<Table id="myTable"
       items="{
       path: 'data>/items'
       }">
```

Comment: Not working! In your case , how the table know which row of data> e.g  data>/0/items or  data>/1/items

Comment: OK, so lets do some systematic diagnosis - if you bind the table to data>/0/items do you get the outcome you would expect? i.e. the table displays the items hanging off type 01?

Comment: this.getView().bindElement("data>/"+ countPath + "/items);